# Matcher assert on two objects

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration-testing, hamcrest

I have an integration test that checks the content type of a response as follows

```
Header header = new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8");

assertThat(response.getEntity().getContentType(), Matchers.is(header));
```

The test fails asserting that the response is same like the pre-built header with this odd message

```
Expected: is <Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8>
    but: was <Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8>
```

My hunch is that since we are speaking of two objects, we are speaking of two different instances. for this I have also tried

```
assertThat(response.getEntity().getContentType(), Matchers.equalTo(header));
```

But the results were the same.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Does the return type of response.getEntity().getContentType() implement `equals` ?

Comment: @StefanBirkner the method returns the BasicHeader of the apache.httpcomponets package. From my investigation this has equals implemented. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Which version has equals overriden? [This one doesn't.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4/org/apache/http/message/BasicHeader.java) Looks like you probably need a custom matcher

Answer (score 1):

it means that `toString` of those two objects give the same results but those objects are different in terms of `equals` method. maybe they have even different classes

Answer (score 1):

Given the equals method is failing on you, an alternative would be to use the reflection equality ignoring the fields that are causing the problem with the equals method

org.mockito.Matchers.refEq(object,[list of fields to ignore])